# disabling specific byobu/screen keybindings that conflict with vim keybindings

Tags: gnu-screen, vim, key-bindings, byobu

`ctrl + a` under byobu has either emacs mode or screen mode. However, I need keybindings like ctrl + a for vim's "increment value" method. How would I prevent byobu/screen from blocking certain keyboard shortcuts?

Note: I get that the function commands are essential to switching screen tabs, so those can stay.. It's really just ther emacs style keybindings I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: in http://diablo.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+byobu i see that you can ctrl a ! to disable key bindings, but I can't personally get that to work..

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of options...

1. You can pass the `ctrl-a` through to vim by pressing `ctrl-a` then
   `a` again.
2. You can switch byobu to use what we call *emacs mode*,
   where `ctrl-a` is not used as an escape (instead, the `F12` is your
   escape).
3. You can do this by running `byobu-ctrl-a emacs` You can
   change byobu's escape sequence entirely using `F9` and selecting
   'Change escape sequence'

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: i was having difficulty getting ctrl-a ctrl-a to work in vim, but after switching to emacs mode, everything works just fine. thank you for your help and byobu!

Comment: Right, so as (1) notes, you'd press 'ctrl-a', let got of 'ctrl' and 'a', and then press an 'a' again.  That would "pass through" the ctrl-a to the application below byobu.

Comment: Yes... but what about the other key bindings such as ESC-x that we use a lot in Emacs? It would be useful if we could momentaneously disable all key bindings while using an application that needs it, and then enable it all back when finished. For the record: sometimes I need to use emacs over an ssh session, so I have to use it inside the terminal.